# Rendering images from root with image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a folder in my root 'root/tmp/database/*.JPG' that I want to show in my view with a `image_tag`.

My current code for this is:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image.file, class: "img-responsive"  %>
<% end %>
```

But because `image_tag` uses the asset pipeline it renders the images as:

```
'/images/tmp/database/xotter-1.jpg'
```

So my question is, is it possible that I use an `image_tag` and get the images rendered as: `'/tmp/database/*.JPG'`

Comment: What's "root" here?  Is it your rails application folder?  All assets used in your site need to come from the application's `public` folder.

Comment: My root is indeed my application folder (i did not know about the app's plubic folder.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All assets (images, css, js etc) served in your website need to come from somewhere inside the public folder.  However, the public folder can contain **symbolic links**, aka shortcuts, to other folders.

So, for example, if you want to serve files from `#{Rails.root}/tmp/database` you can make a symbolic link like so:

```
#from your application folder
cd public
ln -s ../tmp/database database
```

You should now have the appearance of having the `database` folder inside your public folder, and can link to a file in it with the url

```
"/database/xotter-1.jpg"
```

which corresponds to a file at

```
#{Rails.root}/public/database/xotter-1.jpg
```

These instructions assume you are in a bash-style command line shell, eg in linux or mac os.  If you are in windows you may need to set the shortcut up differently.

**EDIT**: an answer to your follow up question about displaying all images in a folder.

Let's say you have a folder `#{Rails.root}/public/database` and you want to find all jpg files in it: you can do that in a variety of ways.  I like `Dir[]`, used with `File.join` (which is a safe way to generate file paths which accounts for extra/missing slashes, which are otherwise easy to get wrong by mistake) eg

```
jpg_files = Dir[File.join("public/database", "*.jpg")]
=> ["public/database/foo.jpg", "public/database/bar.jpg"]
```

Note that these paths are all relative to where the command is run from, which in the case of a rails server or console is the rails application folder.

If you want to link to these, you will need the path relative to the public folder, which you can get by saying

```
filename.gsub("public","")
=> "/database/foo.jpg"
```

So, to tie this together, in your template:

```
<% Dir[File.join("public/database", "*.jpg")).each do |file| %>
  <%= image_tag file.gsub("public",""), class: "img-responsive"  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to `Max Williams`' epic answer, if you populate your `public` folder with your images (instead of `tmp`), you'll be able to use the built-in [`asset_path` helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path):

> Computes the path to asset in public directory

```
asset_path "database/xotter-1.jpg" #-> /public/assets/database/xotter-1.jpg"
```

I appreciate this means you have to use the `assets` subdirectory, but there is a good reason for this...

--

**Precompilation**

Personally, I would put the images into the `assets/images` folder of your app.

The problem you'll have is that all of your images will remain "naked" in your public folder, which will both leave them open to hotlinking, but also prevent their proper use in the asset pipeline.

If you include the images in `assets/images/....`, you get to [`precompile`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) the images when you push to production:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Precompilation puts all the assets into the `/public` folder anyway... but more importantly, [fingerprints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) them:

```
public/assets/images/database/xotter-1-[[fingerprint]].jpg
```

These images will still be available if you call `image_tag databsae/xotter-1.jpg`, but this time they'll be in their correct place.

---

All paths in Rails are taken from the `public` dir, so you can reference a link to the `public` dir directly, by using a relative path:

```
image_tag 'database/xotter-1.jpg
```

The difference is that if you put your images into `assets/images`, they are included in the asset pipeline, and thus will be accessible regardless of the environment you're running your app in.